# How do i retrieve and display a timestamp from a mysql database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

Currently I'm using this line of code

```
echo date("F j Y g:i:s", $row[date]);
```

But it just gives me `January 1 1970 2:33:31`

I also want it to look normal because if I don't do the `date("F j Y g:i:s",` at all, all I get is `2011-03-02 23:00:30` which is the correct date, but displayed in a very abnormal way

Comment: How is that 'date' value stored in MySQL? Integer field? char/varchart? date? datetime? Given what you're getting back from PHP, somehow it's coming back as an integer with value 2131, which is the unix timestamp for Jan 1/70 2:33:31

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typecast to UNIX_TIMESTAMP inside the query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(YourDateField) FROM YourTable
```

Since I see responses to the other answer while this is ignored, let me elaborate:

There are two common date types. Both are actually numbers, that represent a duration since a given date.

1. One is the number of days (float)
   since 1900. One is one day. The
   fraction is the fraction of the day.
2. Other is the number of seconds since 1970. This can be an int (whole seconds) or a float (including fractional seconds).

If you got the first date, but treat it like the second format, you arecounting days for seconds. Instead of 111 years since 1900, you're counting 111 seconds since 1970. That explains why you get that date.

Therefore, use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function, which will convert the first float notation to a timestamp in seconds. It is needed because that is also the type PHP uses.

Comment: "UNIX_TIMESTAMP()" returns an epoch date (seconds since 1970), which can be plugged right into "date('format', $val)"

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to use strtotime, the date functions expects the 2nd parameter to be a unix timestamp

```
date("F j Y g:i:s", strtotime($row[date]));
```

If you want different formatting you can take a look at this page: [Date formatting](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

You might want something like this:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row[date]));
```

Comment: it just gives me this still:

01/01/70January 1 1970 2:00:00

Comment: try var_dump($row[date]) i think your not getting a valid date from your database, maybe you should try $row['date'] (with quotes)

Comment: the quotes didnt help, and what do you mean with the var_dump? what does that do?

Comment: `php >  print date("F j Y g:i:s",strtotime('2011-03-02 23:00:30'));
> March 2 2011 11:00:30`
As you see above strtotime is what you need. Just make sure $row['date'] returns the correct value. Use var_dump($row['data']) to see what is value and type of your variale